# fprintf overwriting other data in C

Tags: c, file-io, printf, file-management

I am trying to write the struct employee to file, but it will only write the most recent entered one, no matter how many times I enter the case statement.

```
    case '1':
    {
        fptr=fopen("program.bin","wb");

        if(fptr==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error!");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("\nA is: %d\n",a);

        printf("\nPlease enter the employee's ID: ");
        scanf("%s",&employee[a].ID);
        fprintf(fptr,"Employees ID number:     %s\r\n",employee[a].ID);

        printf("\nPlease enter the employee's first name: ");
        scanf("%s",&employee[a].firstname);
        fprintf(fptr,"Employees first name:    %s\r\n",employee[a].firstname);

        printf("\nPlease enter the employee's Surname: ");
        scanf("%s",&employee[a].surname);
        fprintf(fptr,"Employees surname:       %s\r\n",employee[a].surname);

        printf("\nPlease enter the employee's Home address: ");
        scanf("%s",&employee[a].address);
        fprintf(fptr,"Employees address is:    %s\r\n",employee[a].address);

        printf("\nPlease enter the employee's department number: ");
        scanf("%s",&employee[a].department);
        fprintf(fptr,"Employees department is: %s\r\n",employee[a].department);

        printf("\nPlease enter the employee's duration: ");
        scanf("%s",&employee[a].duration);
        fprintf(fptr,"Employees duration is:   %s\r\n",employee[a].duration);

        a++;

        fclose(fptr);

        goto CASE; 
     }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the file in `append` mode not in `write` mode.

`fptr=fopen("program.bin","wb");`

this statement opens the file `program.bin` in `binary` `write` mode. This mode means everytime the file is opened, the initial contents of file will be truncated.

You should use:

`fptr=fopen("program.bin","ab");` to open file in `append` mode.

For more details visit [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)

Comment: I think the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) 7.21.5.3 offers a better explanation than that link, since it has a complete list of all combinations of the fopen parameter.

Comment: I thought that would be easy to read and understand for a start.

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the content of the file every time because you're using mode `w` to write the file, which re-writes the file from the beginning. If you simply want to append your data to the end of the file, you should use mode `a` like this:

```
fptr=fopen("program.bin","ab");
//                        ^ Using 'append' mode, rather than 'write' mode.
```